# Allignment issue with the JLabel:

Tags: java, jlabel

I'm trying to align my JLabel at the top of the screen but it is showing at the bottom instead. It can be fixed if put some negative values in the Top-Bottom parameter in setBounds, However ! I wish to know why it's behaving like this and how it can be fixed the other way.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class T2{
private JFrame jf;
private JLabel jL;
private JButton b1, b2;
private JRadioButton jr1;
private JTextField tf1, tf2;
private Font ft;

public void run(){
    //JFrame
    jf = new JFrame("Program");
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setLayout(null);
    jf.setBounds(0,40,500,500);

    //Container
    Container c = jf.getContentPane();

    //Font
    ft = new Font("Consolas",1,25);

    //JLABEL
    jL = new JLabel();
    jL.setText("Enter Name:");
    c.add(jL);;
    //Top-Bottom Positioning isn't working here..
    jL.setBounds(50, 0 , 600, 600);
    jL.setFont(ft);

    //JTextField
    tf1 = new JTextField("Type here...");
    c.add(tf1);
    tf1.setBounds(200, 0 , 200, 20);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    T2 obj = new T2();
    obj.run();
}
}
```

Here's the screenshot:
[LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVxJy.png)

Comment: Using a null layout is never a good idea.  Why don't you use a layout manager?

Comment: Use setLocation as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a layout (the default BorderLayout does what you want), add the components you want to appear at the top to the layout with the constraint "NORTH", then magically it all works.

Further comments in the code.

```
class T2 {

   private JFrame jf;
   private JLabel jL;
   private JButton b1, b2;
   private JRadioButton jr1;
   private JTextField tf1, tf2;
   private Font ft;

   public void run() {
      //JFrame
      jf = new JFrame( "Program" );
      jf.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
//      jf.setVisible( true ); // don't do this until the frame is composed
//      jf.setLayout( null );   // yucky in all respects
//      jf.setBounds( 0, 40, 500, 500 ); // use setSize() instead

      //Container
//      Container c = jf.getContentPane();  // normally you just call add()

      //Font
      ft = new Font( "Consolas", 1, 25 );

      // Make panel first         
      JPanel panelNorth = new JPanel();

      //JLABEL
      jL = new JLabel();
      jL.setText( "Enter Name:" );
      jL.setFont( ft );
      panelNorth.add( jL );
      //Top-Bottom Positioning isn't working here..
//      jL.setBounds( 50, 0, 600, 600 );

      //JTextField
      tf1 = new JTextField( "Type here..." );
//      c.add( tf1 );
      panelNorth.add( tf1 );
//      tf1.setBounds( 200, 0, 200, 20 );

      // now just add the panel to the "north" of the jframe border layout
      jf.add( panelNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH );

      // now make visible
      jf.setSize( 600, 480 );
      jf.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
      jf.setVisible( true );
   }

   public static void main( String args[] ) {

      // Swing is not thread safe, do on EDT
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            T2 obj = new T2();
            obj.run();
         }
      } );
   }
}
```